# How to write for loop to fetch data to newly created file?

Tags: bash

I have scenario where I want to fetch the above 2 lines from where it as matched

I have two files:

**file 1**

```
Ag
Ab
Ah
Av
Ax
```

**file 2**

```
jb:fun_0
jb:fun_jack_0
jb1:Ag

jb:fun_1
jb:fun_jack_1
jb1:Ab

jb:fun_2
jb:fun_jack_3
jb1:Ai

jb:fun_4
jb:fun_jack_4
jb1:Ah

jb:fun_5
jb:fun_jack_5
jb1:Av

jb:fun_5
jb:fun_jack_5
jb1:Al

jb:fun_5
jb:fun_jack_5
jb1:Aj

jb:fun_5
jb:fun_jack_5
jb1:Ax
```

I want to add for loop => like

first it will take the word from file1 => like Ag => try to find Ag in the 
file 2 => if match found then above 2 lines from where it as match should be written to a new text file => demo.txt

my code

```
for j in file1
do
  sr=`grep -i -B2 '$j' file2` 
  echo $sr>>demo.txt  
done
```

But the above code is not working => suggest me

expected output:
Ag match found in file2 => above 2 lines of match should be printed

like output:

```
=======================
jb:fun_0       # 1st line
jb:fun_jack_0  # 2nd line
jb1:Ag         # => match found
=======================
jb:fun_1       # 1st line
jb:fun_jack_1  # 2nd line
jb1:Ab         # => match found
=======================
```

that how the output will on match above 2 lines should be printed

Comment: I can't see the image but basically : 1) iterate over entried in file1 with `while IFS='' read -r variable; do ...; done < file1` 2) use `grep -B 2 "$variable" file2` to retrieve lines containing the entry from file1 and the two lines above (if you don't need the matching line but only the two above, then add `| head -n2`)

Comment: @Aaron can you properly explain its confusing what you have written => if possible can you be able to write proper code using my above code

Comment: Could you add sample input/expected output (file1, file2, demo.txt) so that I can test my answer? I guess they're represented in the linked picture but those of us on corporate networks might not be able to reach content from *.imgur.com (and even for others it's annoying to have to transcribe them)

Comment: @Aaron I have updated the question have a look at it

Comment: Still not quite sure because I still don't know what file1 and file2 contain, but I think you want something like [this](https://ideone.com/sOLK9f) or [that](https://ideone.com/Bi0rV2)

Comment: look at the image or click on image you will get to see the overall overview

Comment: No I won't, I'm on a corporate network which blocks access to *.imgur.com which StackOverflow uses to host its images. Even if I could it would bother me to have to transcribe the pictures to text in order to test a solution, while all you have to do is copy paste the data.

Comment: Looks like my first solution is perfect for you then. I've edited my ideone to make it work on your data : https://ideone.com/3s2v9l

Comment: I got tired of OP being unhelpful, so I transcribed the text myself.

Comment: @melpomene thanks !

Comment: @volmokirti It is not a good idea to "reuse" a question to ask a totally different thing. You should open a new question instead; otherwise all the comments and answers that you already got are useless. I have reverted your last edit and rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
grep -wFB2 -f file2 file1 > demo.txt
```

Detail of the `grep` options :

- `-w` match only full words : avoid matching `Avoid` when looking for `Av`
- `-B2` output the two previous lines in addition to matching lines
- `-f file2` read patterns from file2
- `-F` the patterns are linefeed-separated plain text, not regexs

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/3s2v9l#stdout) !