# Print vertical data in horizontal way

Tags: linux

I have a data which is in vertical form => want to print in horizontal way.

How do I write it to the text file => FILE 2?

DATA I have in **FILE 1**

```
RAM
RAJ 
RAHUL
VIRAJ
```

Data should be Written to the **FILE 2** in this format

**NAME1|NAME2|NAME3|NAME 4**

```
RAM | RAJ | RAHUL | VIRAJ
```

**My code**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print i,$i}'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `tr` shell command to replace end of line characters ("\n") with any sequence, such as "|" in your example:

```
cat file | tr '\n' '|'
```

Comment: What happens on the 5th and 6th lines in the original file?

Comment: @jww The original file has only 4 lines.

Comment: Do you really believe he is asking for a script to format 4 entries? It would be quicker to do that task manually. Or do you think there may be thousands of them?

Comment: @Grodriguez thanks it work for me => I will post another question related to this topic but complex one can you help me out with this

Comment: @jww. What is the problem? There is nothing in my answer that is restricted to 4 entries. It will work in the same way for 40, 400, or 4000.

Comment: @Grodriguez => have a look at another question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362909/print-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want paste:

```
 < input-file paste -d \| - - - - > file2
```